# Select an option in dropdown using a directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I am new to angularjs and working to directive for a dropdown but having problem to select initial value. I have to pass the Id of the option to select as an attribute to the directive. I am setting the attribute value in a scope variable which I then use in ng-Init.

Here is my directive code:

```
export class ChoiceGroup
    {
        constructor ()
        {
            var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
            directive.restrict = "E";
            directive.replace = true;
            directive.template = '<div><select name="cmbCG" ng-model="dataSel" ng-options="c.DisplayName for c in data"></select></div>';
            directive.link = function ($scope: any, element: JQuery, attributes: any) {
                var injector = angular.element(document).injector();
                var key = attributes.key;

                var cgCacheService: ChoiceGroupsCacheService;
                seCGCacheService = injector.get('seChoiceGroupsCacheService');

                var values: Array<ChoiceValue>;
                values = seCGCacheService.GetChoiceValues(key);

                $scope.data = values;
                if (attributes.selectedvalue) {
                    $scope.selectedvalue = values[attributes.selectedvalue];
                }
            }

            return directive;
        }
```

The code is in Typescript. Here is HTML:

```
<choicegroupcombo key="RecurrenceFrequency" selectedvalue="3"></choicegroupcombo>
```

If I hardcode the value of dataSel ie ng-init="dataSel=3" then it works fine but when I set to scope variable then it does not work. So how can I fix the issue.

**EDIT**
Solved. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: What's the actual goal here? Your code doesn't seem to be trying to do anything other than what a normal select box does.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a classic case of "over-engineering".

Your code doesn't seem to be trying to do anything other than what a standard select box does.

Try this instead:

```
app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope) ->
  # $scope.values = ChoiceGroupsCacheService(key)
  $scope.values = [
    { id: 0, label: 'Zero' }
    { id: 1, label: 'One' }
    { id: 2, label: 'Two' }
    { id: 3, label: 'Three' }
  ]
  $scope.number = 2
```

and the view:

```
<select ng-model="number" ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in values"></select>
```

Code is in coffeescript:

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/C6qmUoJ6HjsAT69oavRg

Comment: I need a directive because I want to re-use this dropdown at many places in the application